# best way insert time with zone JavaScript postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql

What is the best way to insert the `now()` date time in postgresql using JavaScript? I've followed some answers but nothing clear, I'd like to find pure JavaScript method, and not with moment.js

Comment: `insert into ... values (now(), ..)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be so much better if you inserted the table's create SQL code, probably part of your application's code in javascript and more information about the situation you're in to your question, in order for people who want to help, to better understand it.

Assuming you have a table with a `createdAt` column which its type is `TIMESTAMP` and you want to fill the query below with proper value for `:nowValue` which is current date and time, and you don't want to use Postgres's built in functionalities (like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) or any other javascript library (like `moment`):

```
INSERT INTO "myTable" ("createdAt") VALUES (:nowValue)
```

First you have to init a new `Date` object:

```js
const nowValue = new Date();
```

Then you can convert the newly created object to string and use it in your query using different methods which return different values:

```js
nowValue.toDateString(); // "Fri Jan 12 2018"

nowValue.toGMTString(); // "Fri, 12 Jan 2018 11:09:43 GMT"

nowValue.toISOString(); // "2018-01-12T11:09:43.153Z"

nowValue.toLocaleDateString(); // "1/12/2018"

nowValue.toLocaleString(); // "1/12/2018, 2:39:43 PM"

nowValue.toUTCString(); // "Fri, 12 Jan 2018 11:09:43 GMT"
```

Some of the above methods only outputs the date and not the time, which will make column's time value to be set to `00:00:00.000000`.
For more detailed information about these methods and how they are different see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date